# Deleted "Resources" Column and now site gives error

Tags: column, sharepoint-calendar

I've deleted the `Resource` column in my calendar list and now, when I have `Use this calendar to share member's schedule` checked YES, I get an error:

> Unable to retrieve 'Resource' field from the current list (Events)

I want to share this calendar, so I need to have that option checked YES, but I'm not sure how to bring back the `Resource` column. I should have hide it, but I didn't think my page would have blown up like this.

Does anyone know why this happens?

More importantly, is there a way to fix this without wiping out my list?

Comment: Can you edit the calendar and edit the content type - Add the column and try again?

Comment: I tried to re-add the Resource column, but it doesn't appear anywhere. When selecting the "Add Existing Site Column" option in Designer, the only resource options are Resource Identifier and Resource Type - neither of which are of the "Resource" type Resource column.

Comment: Check this http://www.dynamics101.com/2013/10/how-to-create-a-resource-calendar-in-sharepoint-2010/ I believe the `Resource` field is a lookup to another list.

Comment: I remember when I looked at it before I axed it that it was classified as a column type "Resource". Of course, this doesn't appear to be a column type you can add. I suppose I need to recreate my calendar list :(

Answer (score 0):

Add the Reservations content type by clicking `Add from existing site content types`. Then you should be able to click `Use this calendar to share member's schedule?`